# Edited post is not what I edited

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This is my first post here because I never found a reason to do so, but this just had to be posted.

So I was just [editing an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4327449) because I thought it wasn't good enough. Now I just formatted some code and made just a little change in spelling. After I did that I went to take a look at the review in my activity, and what I saw was that the post I edited was totally changed!

I did not change the words to "ur" or all of the other things that happened in the edit.
What I edited isn't even in there!

Screenshot:

> [image]

- Can someone tell me what is going on?
- Is this a common thing?
- What to do about this, it will make you look like a fool ?

Comment: So what were the changes submitted by you then? Any proof?

Comment: I got no proof. If I made a wrong edit I will gladly admit it and probably not care that it's rejected because that's a good thing.
But what was done here... I have no clue. I would never make such edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a simple edit collision. You were editing the question at the same time as a user with full editing privileges.

He made more substantial changes, such as modifying "ur" to "your". This got submitted while you were still editing. A couple of seconds later you submitted your suggestion, which was against the first revision of the post. At that point the system "thinks" you changed the corrected "your" back to "ur". Your edits don't appear because most likely the other editor made the exact same ones as well.

And there you go.

Comment: This is exactly what happened I think, but I thought it wasn't possible for two people to edit the same post at the same time?

Comment: It is. It wouldn't be possible for <2k users to edit a post that already has a suggested-edit waiting to be reviewed. But there is no other lock in place to prevent editing by more than one user at a time.

Comment: @MCollard it's very possible, and usually when someone suggests/approved edits quicker than you, a notice "This post has been edited # times, ..." appears on the top of your page.

Comment: What should be done against this, this makes some edits unusable and weird. - See John Willemse reaction.

Comment: @MCollard My suggestion is to ignore it and move-on. It's just an unfortunate event for you, and I doubt this case happens often. In fact, *you've tried to suggest edit in good faith*.